# does storing single fcm token is enough for multiple devices

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a website(Angular) and users who are subscribed for push notifications should get the push notifications for both desktop and mobile. I am using firebase cloud messaging to send notifications and the question is whether storing a single fcm token is enough to send notifications for all devices(note: it is a website). if yes how to do it. any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to store a single token.  You will need to store a token **for each device** that a user actually uses, and associate the token to that user account in your database.  Your FCM server code will then have to query your database to get all the tokens for that user, and send a message to each one of them.